# A question on polynomial ring in continuum many of variables over the integer ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R=\mathbb Z[X_i | i \in \mathbb R ]$ . Does there exist a commutative ring with unity $S$ containing $R$ as a subring such that $S$ has a countable collection of ideals $\{I_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ satisfying : 1) $S/I_n$ is countable $\forall n \in \mathbb N$  and 2) $\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} I_n = \{0\}$  ?

Comment: You may as well require $S=R$, since you can just intersect the ideals with $R$ and conditions (1) and (2) will still hold.

Comment: What does $R$ have to do with $S$, then? Other than "ensuring the ring is large enough"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Consider the ring $S=\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$, for instance.  Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set of $2^{\aleph_0}$ algebraically independent real numbers.  For each $b\in B$, choose a sequence $x(b)\in S$ of rational numbers converging to $B$.  These sequences $x(b)$ will then be algebraically independent in $S$ (any polynomial in them converges to the corresponding polynomial in the $b$'s, and in particular cannot be the zero sequence), and thus generate a subring of $S$ which is isomorphic to $R$.  Now let $I_n\subset S$ be the ideal of sequences whose $n$th coordinate is $0$.  We then have $\bigcap_n I_n=0$, and $S/I_n\cong\mathbb{Q}$ is countable for all $n$ (since $I_n$ is the kernel of the $n$th projection map $S\to\mathbb{Q}$).

(I suspect that in fact pretty much any countably infinite product of countable rings works, as long as the characteristic of the product is $0$.  I just used $\mathbb{Q}$ in order to be able to easily find continuum many algebraically independent elements.)